rememberAsyncImagePainter is not loading images correctly
I am trying to load the images of different user using the image link shared by the api, but neither the "rememberAsyncImagePainter" loading the given image nor it is loading the default image, which I had provided.
It is giving this error when I did the debug :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a fetcher that supports: https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/smiling-young-man-illustration_1308-174669.jpg
    at coil3.intercept.EngineInterceptor.fetch(EngineInterceptor.kt:153)
    at coil3.intercept.EngineInterceptor.execute(EngineInterceptor.kt:115)
    at coil3.intercept.EngineInterceptor.access$execute(EngineInterceptor.kt:32)
    at coil3.intercept.EngineInterceptor$intercept$2.invokeSuspend(EngineInterceptor.kt:66)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:101)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:113)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:89)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:589)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:823)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:720)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:707)

Even though when I copied the url and paste to browser, it is working fine. I humbly request you to help me to solve this issue.
@Composable
fun NewConversationsScreen(state: NewConversationState, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    when {
        state.isLoading -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }

        state.error != null -> {
            Text(text = state.error)
        }

        else -> {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Log.d("NewConvScreen", "Users are : ${state.users.users}")
                items(state.users.users) { user ->
                    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                        model = user.photo
                            ?: "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1683865776032-07bf70b0add1?q=80&w=1932&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
                    )
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        //Profile Photo
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(40.dp)
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(32.dp))
                                .border(1.dp, Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(32.dp))
                        ) {

                            androidx.compose.foundation.Image(
                                painter = painter,
                                contentDescription = "Profile Photo",
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            )

                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                        Text(text = user.name ?: "No Name")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

coil compose version is -> 3.0.4
